# Working bibliography not showing properly

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am having a strange issue, in which the document I am writing has a completely working bibliography, with a real strange issue when displaying. For reference, I leave here what's displaying.

[image]

As a further note, these are the settings of the cls file I am using, that I just imported from a working template on Overleaf.

```
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\RequirePackage[super,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\RequirePackage[comma,numbers]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{[#1]}
\RequirePackage[palatino]{quotchap}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace{1.3\baselineskip}}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\newlength\mybibindent
\setlength\mybibindent{0pt}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
    {\chapter*{\bibname}%
     \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
     \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}
          {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{999}}
           \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\dimexpr\labelsep+\mybibindent\relax\itemindent-\mybibindent
           \@openbib@code
           \usecounter{enumiv}
           \let\p@enumiv\@empty
           \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}
     \sloppy
     \clubpenalty4000
     \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
     \widowpenalty4000%
     \sfcode`\.\@m}
    {\def\@noitemerr
      {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}
     \endlist}

\renewcommand{\backmatter}{
    \begin{appendices}
        \include{chapters/appendixA}
    \end{appendices}
    \input{endmatter/personalize}
    \clearpage
    \bibliography{references}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
    \bibliographystyle{apalike2}
    \include{endmatter/colophon}
}
```

I am deeply sorry for the clumsiness of the question, but I find myself pretty clueless about what could be the problem here.
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: You code is incomplete so we cannot test. Please extend into something others can copy and test as is.

Comment: you are missing `\makeatletter`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: Thank you so much David, I will happily looking forward into it.